# How to change versions of Ruby 1.9 to Ruby 2.0 in the new Windows 10 Bash shell?

Tags: ruby, bash, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded the Bash shell for windows 10. My overall goal is to try and download git and SASS, which seems to be easier in Bash. I successfully upgraded to Ruby version 2.0.0 in the windows cmd prompt using [this website](https://richonrails.com/articles/ruby-2-2-on-windows).

Whenever I type the bash command in the cmd prompt and it switches over to bash; I type in `sudo apt-get install ruby`. It still only will download to ruby 1.9. I am new to bash so maybe don't understand how it works but I thought I can access Windows folders through bash and vice versa. Anyone have experience on how to find/download ruby 2.0 or higher in the bash for windows 10?

Update: I just installed ruby in the bash and the current version is 1.9 but I successfully downloaded ruby 2.0. So now how do I change versions?

Comment: I used to use the ``pik`` gem (no longer maintained) to have multiple versions on ruby on a windows machine. Now I would explore: https://bitbucket.org/jonforums/uru

Comment: I would look into Ruby Version Manager (rvm.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, WSL is based on Ubuntu 14.04, so there are no recent Ruby versions available with the official apt repos.

You can install Ruby 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3 via [Brightbox/ruby-ng](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) ppa repository if you prefer managing packages with apt.

Quoting from the Brightbox site:

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ sudo apt-get update
```

And then,

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.1
```

Otherwise, [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) is an another option to achieve that.